# Click and element on a map with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, dictionary

I am trying to click every element on the map at https://www.coronavirus.in.gov/2393.htm to get the details for every county but I not able to do so, I have tried the two approaches below but none of them have worked.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
start_url = "https://www.coronavirus.in.gov/2393.htm"
driver.get(start_url)
time.sleep(15)

# First attempt to click element first element on top left corner
element = driver.find_element_by_id('id-4957')
element.click()

# Second attempt to select the element
hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element)
hover.perform()

driver.quit()
```